# Android - GridView image not displaying correctly after orientation change

Tags: android, gridview, android-glide

In my Android app I display photos in a GridView. I do some heavy processing in those photos before loading them into the GridView, so I decided to handle the configuration change myself by overriding the onConfigurationChanged() method, which only changes the number of columns of the GridView and then reassigns the adapter to it.
When I switch the device from landscape to portrait everything works perfectly, and the image takes the entire column space, as expected.
But when I switch the device from portrait to landscape, the width of the images in the GridView is a lot less than it needs to be.
I'm using Glide library to load photos into the GridView.

How can I do to solve this?

My code is as follows:

```
public class PhotosAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> images;

    public PhotosAdapter(ArrayList<String> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return images.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        if(row == null) {
            //No tenemos vista reciclada, la creamos
            row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_row, parent, false);
        }

        TickedImageView thumbV = (TickedImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
        int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int numberOfColumns = Utils.landscape(PhotosActivity.this) ? 5 : 3;
        int width = screenWidth / numberOfColumns;

        thumbV.setDrawingWidth(width);

        //Por si la TickedImageView fue reciclada, la desmarcamos
        thumbV.setSelected(selectedPaths.contains(images.get(position)));

        thumbV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TickedImageView view = (TickedImageView) v;

                if (view.isSelected())
                    selectedPaths.add(images.get(position));
                else
                    selectedPaths.remove(images.get(position));
            }
        });

        //Cargamos la imagen
        Glide.with(PhotosActivity.this)
                .load(new File(images.get(position)))
                .centerCrop()
                .into(thumbV);

        Log.d("TAG", images.get(position));
        return row;
    }

    public void removeImage(String image) {
        images.remove(image);
    }
    public String getImage(int position) {
        return images.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be experiencing [this issue](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/613), try setting the ImageView size to `match_parent` in XML, and set the column count on the GridView, no need for custom `drawingWidth`. The rest should be taken care of by the Android layout system laying out GridView and Glide.

*Minitip: you can say `public String getItem` because of covariant return types, one less method by not having the duplicated `getImage`.*

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the seperate layout for landscape mode and configure no. of columns of Grid as 
1 + no.Of columns in Portrait mode.
also, have scaleType = centerCrop for your imageView
Android will take care of the rest.